# how to install gcc7 in docker centos7

Tags: docker, gcc, centos7

I am trying to build an docker image based on `centos7`

```
FROM centos:centos7

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install gcc
RUN gcc --version
```

the installed `gcc` is 4.8:

Step

```
 4/4 : RUN gcc --version
 ---> Running in 70b9aa4a1f67
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How can I install gcc7? I tried devtools-7, it does not work:

```
FROM centos:centos7

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install scl-utils
RUN yum -y install devtoolset-7-gcc
RUN scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
RUN gcc --version
```

I got:

```
Step 4/6 : RUN yum -y install devtoolset-7-gcc
 ---> Running in 85b49f411d4c
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * extras: mirror.23media.com
 * updates: ftp.plusline.net
No package devtoolset-7-gcc available.
Error: Nothing to do
The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y install devtoolset-7-gcc' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Following commands in Dockerfile worked for me:

```
RUN yum install -y centos-release-scl
RUN yum install -y devtoolset-7-gcc-*
RUN echo "source scl_source enable devtoolset-7" >> /etc/bashrc
RUN source /etc/bashrc
```

Answer (score 4):

```
FROM centos:centos7
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y    
RUN yum install wget -y
RUN curl -O https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-7.3.0/gcc-7.3.0.tar.gz
RUN tar xzf gcc-7.3.0.tar.gz
RUN cd gcc-7.3.0
RUN ./contrib/download_prerequisites
RUN cd ..
RUN mkdir gcc-build
RUN cd gcc-build
RUN ../gcc-7.3.0/configure                           \
    --enable-shared                                  \
    --enable-threads=posix                           \
    --enable-__cxa_atexit                            \
    --enable-clocale=gnu                             \
    --disable-multilib                               \
    --enable-languages=all
RUN make
# (Go make a cup of ice tea :)
RUN make install
```

To save the build time you can create a new docker from the running docker using "docker commit" or save /usr/local to a tar file and open it on any other fresh centos7 docker.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It indeed solves the question however building from the source makes the build process complex and time consuming, it would better if the solution is installed from pre-built.

Comment: Pre-built binaries are by definition built with a specific libc so each CentOS OS version will have only one version of GCC pre-built binaries, the latest OS will have the latest GCC and older versions will be stuck with old GCC, maybe building the GCC7 source rpms on CentOS7 will do the trick.

Comment: This solution takes a long time and my console returns an error then stop.

Comment: --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new for newer _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI enabled

Comment: download_prereq need a tweak - using https://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/ and --no-verify

Comment: useful link to test it https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1546704

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, devtoolset-7-gcc doesn't exist in your current repository configuration. Try adding a repo having it, or try `yum -y install centos-release-scl` instead of `yum -y install  scl-utils`.

Found it here : http://blog.stevedoria.net/20180214/how-to-install-gcc-7-on-centos-7

Have fun!

Edit:

After some more research, it seems that gcc 7 is indeed installed but scl enable is actually opening a new bash which will contain your GCC 7. If you really need to have GCC 7 as you default gcc, you can compile it from source (but it take a loooong time), or you can use the SHELL command from your dockerfile to alternate between shells. Here my docker file :

```
FROM centos:centos7

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install centos-release-scl
RUN yum -y install devtoolset-7-gcc*
SHELL [ "/usr/bin/scl", "enable", "devtoolset-7"]
RUN gcc --version
```

And the output of `RUN gcc --version`

```
gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Alterning between shells seems to be the intended way to do it when using the devtoolset, because it allow you to switch between version quickly if needed.
I hope this helped

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work, I keep getting gcc 4.8

Comment: You really should try your self and getting a working dockerfile that containing gcc7 message. I have searched solution over google for a long time

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work :( I'll try it myself when I get the time.

Comment: I edited my response with some solution I found. Tell me what you think about it

Comment: It will only work with 

SHELL [ "/usr/bin/scl", "enable", "devtoolset-7", "bash"]

Answer (score 0):

Simply sourcing the profile won't work. You need to run you script with `bash -l`. For instance:

```sh
docker run --rm [YOUR IMG] bash -l [YOUR SCRIPT]
```

Then new version GCC will be enabled.